# Best practice to extract the value from Form Array angular 12

Tags: angular

FormArray not working on angular 12!
**In TS file**

```
     this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      id: [''],
      ctId: [''],
      custId: [''],
      clients: this._formBuilder.array([]),
     
    });

  }
  createUser(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      address: '',
      phone: '',
      email: ''
    });
  }
  addClient(): void {
    this.refs = this.thirdFormGroup.get('clients') as FormArray;
    this.clients.push(this.createUser());
  }
```

**in HTML file**

```
     <div formArrayName="clients">
                <div *ngFor="let creds of thirdFormGroup.get('clients').controls; let i = index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
```

I have tried multiple ways but no luck!

See what I have tried...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d5uaqx?file=src/app/app.component.html

Finally I have ended-up with below solution

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @yurzui

I have added the below code in HTML file

```
      *ngFor="let client of clients.controls; let i = index"...
```

and in ts file

```
  get credentials() {
    return this.form.controls.clients as FormArray
  }
```

This is the working solution.!

Is it the best practice to get the value from FormArray? If not then what it would be? I appreciate the clean code.

Comment: Have you tried to search similar issues with the same error message? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+Property+%27controls%27+does+not+exist+on+type+%27AbstractControl%27

Comment: yes @yurzui and tried most of them but it did not work!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d5uaqx?file=src/app/app.component.html

 check this

Comment: @yurzui same code is working on another version but it's not working on version 12? am I in trouble?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-relphk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Raj, I **always** when use a FormArray I use a getter

```
get refArray(){
  return this.thirdFormGroup.get('refs') as FormArray;
}
```

And iterate over this.

```
<div *ngFor="let creds of refArray.controls>
..
</div>
```

NOTE: Yet in early Angular 7, you should use a getter when you build in production the angular app -althoughts works in development-

Comment: your suggestion works well too! I am using the Angular 12 version..Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried many corners of the internet but those solutions never worked for me, luckily I found the only solution that worked for me:

```
let creds of $any(thirdFormGroup.get('refs')).controls
```